# Difference between Es muss geregnet haben vs Es hätte regnen müssen

Tags: subjunctive

what is the difference between these two sentences:

- Es muss geregnet haben = "It must have rained"
- Es hätte regnen müssen = again "It must have rained"?

Comment: Check whether any of these posts help you. If not, expand on your question a bit. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/799/bedeutungsunterschied-zwischen-h%c3%a4tte-machen-sollen-and-sollte-gemacht-haben https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35584/konjunktiv-ii-with-modal-verbs/35592#35592 https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/german-modal-verbs-in-perfect-tense-two-ways

Answer (score 4):

Your supected translations are wrong. They should be

- Es muss geregnet haben = "It must have been raining"
- Es hätte regnen müssen = "It should have been raining"